# lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand in c function pointer

Tags: c

My code is below and problem is also explained below with why the `lvalue` is happening;

```
typedef struct test_item
{
    char id[MENU_NAME_LEN + NULL_SPACE];
    MenuFunction function;
} test_item;
```

and

```
 typedef void (*MenuFunction)(VmSystem *);
```

and

```
void display(VmSystem * system)
{
    printf("test");
}
```

I am able to assign the ID with what I want however when i try to assign the function pointer I get the following error `lvalue` required as unary `&` operand

```
test_item test;
test.function = &display(system);
```

Comment: A function name followed by `()` means calling a function. A function name without `()` means the function address.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here, but `&display(system)` is asking C to provide you with the address of the return value from a function called `display`. However, this value is returned in a processor register; it doesn't have an address at all. So the line `test.function = &display(system);` makes no sense.

Comment: @Johnny S  Write test.function = **********display;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You meant:

```
test.function = display;
```

The `()` after `display` means to call that function. Just `display` will evaluate to a pointer to the function. There is no need for `&display`.

Comment: thanks, when i try to call it later on i get the following message, what have done wrong this time -  "passing argument 1 of ‘test->function’ from incompatible pointer type" i am calling it by this code snippet; test.function(system)

Comment: @JohnnyS And what is `system`? It's a shady variable name, since it shadows [the standard function of the same name](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) which might lead to trouble.

Comment: i read that  "typedef void (*MenuFunction)(VmSystem *);" the second () is the input for the function so it was just a name for VmSystem however i am probably wrong

Comment: @JohnnyS No, that's right, the function needs a pointer to a `VmSystem`.

Comment: Any idea how to call the function later on in my code? i have tried test.function(system); and it wont work. :(

Comment: @JohnnyS Yes, but I don't know the type of your variable `system`, or how to create an instance of `VmSystem`, so I can't write that code. You need to provide more context.

Comment: can you provide me with the general use case then, and i'll try to do it system has already been created and just gets passed around the program @unwind

Comment: @JohnnyS You need to show a bit more code. Where do you define `system` and how do you use it. Our crystall balls are a bit blurred at the moment.

Comment: @JohnnyS Already the comments to your question ask you about a "Minimum **Complete** Verifiable Example"